# Javascript onblur() wont work when directly click on button

Tags: javascript, onblur

I got a javascript textbox, it has onblur() and it will call a validation function, so suppose when i focus out from the textbox, it will trigger the onblur() and validate the data which users input, then i click on a button "submit", it will process the data.

There is a bug where when i type something in the textbox, then i click on the submit button immediately (without focus out from textbox first), so actually it will NOT trigger the 
onblur() and WONT validate the data in the textbox, even if the data is wrong, it will process the data because calling onblur() failed.

In this case, how to solve this bug IF i dont want any validation in the button (onclick event). Tried onchange(), also failed.

Answer (score 0):

onblur() function will call, if you access certain textbox only. Otherwise it will not call before you submit it.

So I suggest you to write a validation method and call it onsumbit() also.

Comment: hi, sorry im quite new to javascript, i quite not get ur explanation       "onblur() function will call, if you access certain textbox only. Otherwise it will not call before you submit it." What do u mean by access certain textbox only? From what i understand, onclick is triggered when button is being clicked, and onsumbit is triggered when form is being submitted.

Comment: onblur is an event, which will call when you leave the textbox. I mean focus out the textbox. If you didn't try to edit the text box, you are not focus out. So onblur event will not trigger. So your function will not call.

If you add your code, it will help to explain.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp
If you can't understand from this link. google it, you can find more good explanations. That will help you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As you not added code I only give suggestion. (please add the sample fiddle for more investigation)

You can use focus event of button to validate or focus out of textarea.

```
$("button").focus(function() { // validation  
} );

$( "textarea" ).focusout(function() { // validation   
});
```

Though best approach in onsubmit of form.